# What is the best way for a database design with fixed number of contact persons?

Tags: sql, database, structure, database-normalization

I am currently designing a database for a project. I'd like to normalize it and I have come across a question that I would like to ask in a larger group, especially with regard to previous experiences.

About the situation: An organization has 0 to 4 contact partners. Of the four contact partners, two are on-site to the organization (local) and two are available throughout the country (global).

On an input mask, a user can select which contact from the contacts table is so-called "local contact partner 1", "local contact partner 2", "global contact partner 1" etc., so the order (order, "1" or "2") is relevant.

What would be the best way to structure the database? I have attached three examples, but please feel free to make other suggestions.

[image: 3 Database Examples]

Comment: `isLocalContact` <-> `isGlobalContact`: Can a contact be both local as well as global, or none of both? If not, I'd skip one of them as redundant – alternatively `contactType` with distinct values for local/global (and maybe later on other types -> flexibility.

Comment: Apart from, third model appears superior to me, as you remain most flexible (company might decide to add yet another type of contacts, e. g. Europe, or might decide that two contacts of the same type are not sufficient any more due to growth). Second model is somehow only a hybrid between first and third, inheriting the disadvantages of both of the other ones, so that one I'd skip first.

Comment: Is it possible for one contact to be local and global at the same time?

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks for your comment, these are good points that you bring up! I will take those into account too.

Comment: @SalmanA If I think about it, no it wouldn't be possible that one contact is both.

Comment: Then you could combine them into one field e.g. ContactType (values 1 and 2) just to be sure that one cannot set a contact as both types by mistake.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend The 3rd solution. At one day in the future the business will come up with an exception and state an organization can have 5 or more contacts.
If the primary key of OrganiationContacts is organizationId+ContactId you also have the guarantee the same contact cannot be both local and global or defined twice as contact. The other structures cannot guarantee this and require additional validation logic.